# How do we erase keychain data in TestFlight apps?

Tags: ios, keychain, mobile-development

I’m using TestFlight to test my build. I want to erase keychain data to test some behavior. How is this possible?

Comment: You either need to erase the device or add code to your app to remove the keychain item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a secure wipe of the device or reset iOS, then you get clean keychain. However, the best way is to implement erasing you keychain variables in code.